# Carry a variable across two files in different classes

Tags: python, class, methods, static, global

I want to carry the variable user once a person is logged in, to another file that will populate or carry over that user variable so that I can use it in an SQL Statement.

```
    def ViewScore(self, event):
    root = Tk()
    root.title("You last 5 attempts for this topic")
    user = user_management.getuser()
    app = UserScore(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The variable user works, ive tested it using the print statments, however I need to carry it over to the UserScore.py file and run an SQL statement.

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM scores where username="%s" and topic="binary" order by ID DESC' % (user)
```

The user variable there in the sql statement seems to never get populated or created, I just dont know how to do it.

UserScore.py

```
class UserScore(Frame):

   def __init__(self,master):
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.pack()
    self.getRecords()


   def getRecords(self):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the function that sets `sql` is some kind of GUI callback, not something you'd be calling directly with arguments. Have you tried calling a function in `UserScore.py` that sets a global variable, then having the function that sets `sql` access that global variable?

Probably not the most Pythonic way to do it - should probably do it with a class instance - but it should work and it's simple.

Edit: To clarify:

In the function that can access user, add this:

```
import UserScore
UserScore.user = user
```

In `UserScore.py`, put this near the top:

```
user = None
```

Then in the UserScore.UserScore function, just access the variable `user`.

(Probably not a good idea to give the module and class the same name with same capitalization, can get confusing.)

Comment: Well the UserScore.py is setup like so-

`class UserScore(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.pack()
        self.getRecords()
        
        
    def getRecords(self):`
Will the global variable be accessed in that code too? Do i need to declare it in the init method?

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I have solved the problem using your suggested solution.

Comment: Good, just remember it's not Pythonic, or the best way. Just a simple way.